# Unable to insert data from listview to sql database

Tags: c#, sql

```
foreach ( ListViewItem l in lvSA.Items)
{
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = .; database = ePartyDatabase; integrated security = true");
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PARTY_ROOMS(PR_ROOMNO,PR_RATES,PR_REMARK) values(" + l.SubItems[1].ToString() + "," + l.SubItems[3].ToString() + l.SubItems[4].ToString(), con);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
}
```

Comment: And your question is? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list (and use parameterized SQL - your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks)

Comment: **What is your question?** Which line throws an exception or giving an error? Be more specific..

Answer (score 1):

Should it be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PARTY_ROOMS(PR_ROOMNO,PR_RATES,PR_REMARK) values('" + l.SubItems[1].Text + "','" + l.SubItems[3].Text + "','" + l.SubItems[4].Text + "')", con);
```

?

Comment: after compiling ur code i got "Incorrect syntax near 'ListViewSubItem: {104}'."

Comment: sorry, yes it is working....

Comment: Andrey i got this output after inserting the data through lisview-

Comment: ListViewSubItem: {102} ListViewSubItem: {1500} ListViewSubItem: {qweqw}

Comment: That's because you use `ToString()` method of `SubItem` object. Try to use `l.SubItems[1].Text` instead. That should give you the actual value of `l.SubItems[1]`

Comment: oh yeh!!! finally i got the correct output. thank you dear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave us a few information, I assume your `SqlCommand` have some problem.

You tried to insert 3 column (`PR_ROOMNO`,`PR_RATES`,`PR_REMARK`) but in your VALUES part, you had 2 value;

- `l.SubItems[1].ToString()` and
- `l.SubItems[3].ToString() + l.SubItems[4].ToString()`

I think you need to seperate your second value to two values, like;

```
values('" + l.SubItems[1].ToString() + "','" + l.SubItems[3].ToString() + "','" + l.SubItems[4].ToString() + "')", con);
```

Check out how you can use *[INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)* from *MSDN*.

And remember, always use  *[`parameterized SQL`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* queries. Your code is open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

Comment: thanks for ur reply sir but i got the output.